# Proving Hoeffeding's lemma

Tags: probability-theory

For $X$ a real-valued random variable such that $|X| \leq 1$ a.s., I need to prove the following by using the Jensen's inequality:$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda x}] \leq \cosh(\lambda) \leq e^{\lambda^2/2}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}.$$ I do not see how to include the Jensen's inequality here. Can you provide any suggestion or a solution proposal in proving the two inequalities ? Many thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma

Comment: You are asking for a proof of  basic result (which even has  a name!). Did you try to find a proof on the net or in a  book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without loss of generality, by replacing $X$ by $X - \mathbb{E}[X]$, we can assume $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$, so that $a \leq 0 \leq b$.
>
> Since $e^{\lambda x}$ is a convex function of $x$, we have that for all $x \in [a,b]$,
>
> $$e^{\lambda x}\leq \frac{b-x}{b-a}e^{\lambda a}+\frac{x-a}{b-a}e^{\lambda b}$$
>
> So,
> $$\begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda X}\right] &\leq \frac{b-\mathbb{E}[X]}{b-a}e^{\lambda a}+\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]-a}{b-a}e^{\lambda b}\\
> &=  \frac{b}{b-a}e^{\lambda a} + \frac{-a}{b-a}e^{\lambda b} \\
> &= e^{L(\lambda(b-a))},
> \end{align*}
> $$
>
> where $L(h)= \frac{ha}{b-a}+\ln(1 + \frac{a - e^ha}{b-a})$. By computing derivatives, we find
>
> $$L(0)=L'(0)=0 \text{ and } L''(h)= -\frac{ab e^h}{(b-a e^h)^2}$$
>
> From the AM-GM inequality we thus see that $L''(h)\le\frac14$ for all $h$, and thus, from Taylor's theorem, there is some $0 \le \theta \le 1$ such that
>
> $$ L(h) = L(0) + h L'(0) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 L''(h\theta) \leq \frac{1}{8}h^2.$$
>
> Thus, $ \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda X}\right] \leq e^{\frac{1}{8}\lambda^2(b-a)^2}$.

This is directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma). Before you ask a question, please search the internet for any answers.